# Множественное число сказуемого с местоимением "кто"

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, согласование, сказуемые, местоимения

*Затем в комнату зашли три молодых человека.*

*Кто это были?* / *Кто были эти люди?*

Можно ли так спросить, несмотря на правило о том, что при подлежащем — вопросительном местоимении "кто" глагол-сказуемое ставится в форме единственного числа, а в прошедшем времени – в мужском роде, независимо от числа производителей действия и их принадлежности к мужскому или женскому полу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сказать: Кто были эти люди? Ср.: Кто были твои друзья? Здесь т. н. обратное согласование.

**См.:  Былинский К. И.. Литературное редактирование : учеб. пособие / К.И. Былинский, Д.Э. Розенталь. 3-е изд., испр. и доп. — М. : ФЛИНТА : Наука. — 400 с. - (Стилистическое наследие).. 2011**

Comment: Но "Кто это были?" - так нельзя писать.

Comment: @М_Г,  конечно ,нельзя.

Comment: Разве нельзя? Представьте ситуацию. Три человека вышли из комнаты и вы спрашиваете у своего приятеля: "Кто это были?"

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко, Розенталь не согласен.